# Phrases with Multiple Auxiliary Verbs

Tags: phrase-requests, speech, auxiliary-verbs

I'm sorry if this question is already asked. I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere in the internet. My question is:

What are the common phrases with multiple auxiliary verbs which are used to make sentences??

Eg: 
1. "have to do" - "You have to see a doctor"
2. "should have done" - "you should have attended the class"
3. "could have done" - "I could have gone to the movies, if I had cleaned the house"

I need a list of common phrases like this. Because learning this kind of phrases and its usage can really help English learners. It will be quote useful in the daily life.

I request all of you to please share the phrases you know.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple auxiliary verbs"?